# wsl on an older system?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

*I have a machine with a dual core core 2 duo and 3 gigs of ram. I have to run some **linux** applications for school and I'm not sure if my system will be able to handle this much load.*

**So should I try to install/run *wsl* on such an older system?**

Comment: Linux command-line applications or applications with GUI? The latter is not supported by any released WSL version at the moment.

Comment: just the command line, but i was thinking of using xming to run "ns2", i don't think i will consume that much recourses(or will it?), I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use WSL on my computer, and it normally does not use too much resources. Though I mainly use it to edit and run code, it takes up far less system resources than the Windows operating system itself or even a browser. However, it should be noted that WSL does take quite a bit of disk space (it takes more than one gigabyte on my computer). If WSL does not work for you, you can alternatively consider installing a lightweight Linux distribution (perhaps even a CLI one) alongside Windows or on a portable drive (ex. a USB).

Comment: Actually I have enough rom in my system, the only problem is processing power and ram. That's why i wanted to confirm. Now that you say that it does not consume much resources, I think it should be file to run cli only for wsl.